# OTF font type and "Alternate characters"

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, .ttf

I purchased a nice font in an OTF font file. It also installed nicely with the font-application in my home directory and is accessible by eg libreoffice.

Now for the tricky part: the font-file contains characters which are called "stylistic alternates" and are advertised as such, which is OK with me, but no use for me so far.

What amazes me is that these "Stylistic alternates" are offered in LibreOffice and I really cannot get the "Originals" to work in the standard setting.

For example the A must look like this (char 0x41 (U+0041)) :

[image]

but looks like this, take note of the horizontal part of the A (char 0x10004 (U+0041)) :

[image]

This is the font Planjer bought from "Fontspring" [[link]](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/typefaith-fonts/planjer) which is OK.

In Windows the characters come over OK. The right 'A' is chosen.

Further in the Font app, the characters are shown like this : 
[image]

And when double-clicked, like this, watch the "A":
[image]

When using the characters app, the alternate A is also shown :
[image]

When used in, ahum, Windows (10) this is no problem and the correct A is shown.

I am using :
Ubuntu 18.04
LibreOffice 6.0.7.3

It seems a "low level" (OS?) problem to me. But I hope somebody can help me.

greetings

Pieter